# Time Machine wants to backup all files after permission change — how to avoid?

Tags: macos, time-machine, permission

I have been using Time Machine on 10.9.5 for a long time now, and it was working flawlessly until today.

This morning a friend of mine tried to access a freshly set up NFS share of my Music folder, but couldn't read any files due to their permissions.

So I went ahead and ran `chmod -R 755 ./*` on the whole Music folder, which is roughly 600 GB in size.

And so, now it wouldn't backup at all, telling me this:

[image: Imgur]

The error message keeps on appearing, altering across my two backup disks, none of which obviously have the required 600 GB of space.

Is there any way I could tell it to ignore permissions on that specific folder, or somehow retrieve the permissions without restoring the whole folder from the last backup?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So I had to go ahead and put back all the permissions like so (FISH shell):


    for i in ~/Music/**
        chown (stat -f%u:%g "/Volumes/.../Backups.backupdb/.../.../Macintosh HD/Users/.../Music/$i") "~/Music/$i"
        chmod (stat -f%Mp%Lp "/Volumes/.../Backups.backupdb/.../.../Macintosh HD/Users/.../Music/$i") "~/Music/$i"
    end

After that the `tmutil compare` shows a change that's more like it:

    -------------------------------------
    Added:         901.8M
    Removed:       989.0M
    Changed:       1.4G

However the problem is still present, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just had to erase my time machine disks and start from scratch.
It seems to work fine now, but this is not how it should have worked.

So I would be looking into moving from Time Machine in favor of something more reliable and avoiding TM further at all costs.